# How can I install php8.2-intl on Ubuntu 23-10?

Tags: php, 23.10

How do I get past this refusal to install internationalization support in PHP 8.2?

```
$ sudo apt-get install php8.2-intl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php8.2-intl : Depends: php8.2-common (= 8.2.10-2ubuntu1) but         8.2.14-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried every suggestion I can find on this or any other forum and NOTHING will convince the system to install this feature.  I don't understand.  PHP 8.2 is the default version of PHP that comes with Ubuntu 23-10.  Why does everything else except php8.2-intl install without a problem?  Why is php8.2-intl DEMANDING the obsolete 8.2.10?

Comment: What is the output of `apt policy php8.2-common`? it looks like an incompatible PPA may be involved

Comment: `sudo apt-get install http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php8.2/php8.2-common_8.2.10-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb`  https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/23.10/ubuntu-main-amd64/php8.2-common_8.2.10-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb.html  If they can co-exist, it would satisfy apt.

Comment: $ apt policy php8.2-common
php8.2-common:
  Installed: 8.2.14-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 8.2.14-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
 *** 8.2.14-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.2.10-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 Packages

Comment: As I understand it all of the PHP8.2 packages that I have installed, including php8.2-common are at level 8.2.14-1, but the only candidate for php8.2-intl is from 8.2.10-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/universe amd64 Packages.  From where do I obtain a version of php8.2-intl at level 8.2.14-1?

Comment: My website has not been down for **five days** because I cannot install php8.2.instl.  PLEASE CAN ANYONE SUGGEST A SOLUTION?

Answer (score 1):

The pacakage `php8.2-intl` is available from Universe repository.

Remove third party repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ondrej/php
```

Then:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt purge php8.2
sudo apt install php8.2
```

Comment: Thank you.  I issued those four commands but I still get: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php8.2-intl : Depends: php8.2-common (= 8.2.10-2ubuntu1) but 8.2.14-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @JamesCobban See my edit please.

Comment: GAD3R I issued all of the commands you suggested and I still cannot install php8.2-intl

Comment: @JamesCobban Could you add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do:

sudo `apt purge php8.2*` to completely remove all traces of PHP8.2 then I had to install PHP8.2 from the Mantic repository along with all of the features that I had installed.  That meant REMEMBERING all the features I had installed.  My web-site is now up.

Thank you to all the people who responded, and please forgive my ignorance.  I have no idea whence I obtained the 8.2.14-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 packages.  Observe that was almost TWO YEARS AGO, since they were to apply to PHP 8.2 on the LTS Jammy release!